# How to fix "The connection was reset" on nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, nginx-config

I use nginx inside a docker container and I'm unable to connect to it properly.

The error inside the browser is:

> The connection was reset

if I try to curl inside the container I get:

> /usr/share/nginx/html # curl localhost
>   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chmod -R a+w /var/cache/nginx/ \
        && touch /var/run/nginx.pid \
        && chmod a+w /var/run/nginx.pid

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
```

My command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 <mycontainer>
```

My default.conf:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /pointeuse/index.html;
  }
}
```

This is my container inspect:

```
 [
    {
        "Id": "sha256:b431c5a40e599a69a31f482d52ba3a971953bece09d7de1a83d3ff78bd08e79b",
        "RepoTags": [
            "test:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:52a9dfb246091e9a6fedc6e7bdc7c701dd39638bd3889ae098bb97d519889c2f",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2020-05-23T12:27:30.123757764Z",
        "Container": "70cfa14de670aaf2c599385b1afbf5d5f4a155ce2e655031b1adcaa3654e5442",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "70cfa14de670",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.17.10",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.3.9",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "EXPOSE 80"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:52a9dfb246091e9a6fedc6e7bdc7c701dd39638bd3889ae098bb97d519889c2f",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.9",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.17.10",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.3.9",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:52a9dfb246091e9a6fedc6e7bdc7c701dd39638bd3889ae098bb97d519889c2f",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 31180356,
        "VirtualSize": 31180356,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/462dd80fe58a733771808738b12b51fc08995c7a7f7b58c240404067e742fb13/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d91f7871375c57d25380a3f72afbe453cc3044ae6648037d7810c771ff34b873/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b7177dbb104d4ad8da12fe2c0bf11e62d7c5a4e731572bf2677c3c0e576087f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f555e278efd118a189669ebf977d14e3ee0a9b1ac2440191bbcf77ceb693378/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/72bac5710e111f45c9ef6cd0cddfae079c91bb007d9fa3fe79eda283f2bbf318/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/72bac5710e111f45c9ef6cd0cddfae079c91bb007d9fa3fe79eda283f2bbf318/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/72bac5710e111f45c9ef6cd0cddfae079c91bb007d9fa3fe79eda283f2bbf318/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:3e207b409db364b595ba862cdc12be96dcdad8e36c59a03b7b3b61c946a5741a",
                "sha256:3810cc0c140fd3afda75475ae08152cd1a6643962a18cc51a2de1c061f01ed7b",
                "sha256:9bb57ece8be2135a6f230901f9a66353f9d0f9134b36f85570b93bd812c9938b",
                "sha256:b3fc9f22b63668bb906ccefb28113ec4b7aab6cbdd569c3cbccfbcd9f49a6ca1",
                "sha256:9f2edf038c0c3a17430487323ef682150a2c7a4aade35f30b42b76f84b88ebdc"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2020-05-23T14:27:30.168712086+02:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What is you `docker run` command?

Comment: I edited the question .

Comment: Can you share the result of `docker-machine ls` to check the container's host IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to reach your nginx container because you try to connect to it with ipv4 and in your configuration file you use an ipv6 syntax.

Change to `listen 80`.

Answer (score -1):

Your dockerfile doesn't start the nginx service. You need to run `nginx -g daemon off;` Use this Dockerfile instead:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chmod -R a+w /var/cache/nginx/ \
        && touch /var/run/nginx.pid \
        && chmod a+w /var/run/nginx.pid

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Hello, indeed the nginx daemon is running in my container because this line is already specified into the nginx:alpine image as you can see on the official nginx:alpine image on github. https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/594ce7a8bc26c85af88495ac94d5cd0096b306f7/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile Furthermore, you can find this command into the inspect logs... In the other hand, I noticed  in the same time that it was overkill to EXPOSE the port 80 twice. I removed the EXPOSE line and the behavior didn't changed as well. Thank you for your reply.